# .htaccess url rewriting issue - redirecting every request to sub directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i have following htaccess file which redirecting every link to **/love/tribe-world** directory (including root also).

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (?!^/campaigners/)^(.*)$ /love/tribe-world/campaigners/$1 [L,QSA]
```

i have written above rules for hiding **/love/tribe-world** directory from url. i wanted url **www.example.com/campaigners/start-process** instead **www.example.com/love/tribe-world/campaigners/start-process**, which is working using above rule.

But its redirecting every request to the **/love/tribe-world** which is strength for me.

Can anyone guide me what i am doing wrong here...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lookahead is incorrect. Use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(campaigners.*)$ /love/tribe-world/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: i wants to rewrite url only for "campaigners" to /love/tribe-world.. i have tried your code but its still issue exists.

Comment: root is working it seems but /campaingers/start-process stoped working

Comment: Sorry bro but its not even redirecting, giving me blank white page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65191/discussion-between-kalpit-and-anubhava).

Comment: have added [L,NC,R] and in url its showing /campaigners/start-process only.. its not redirecting it seems

Comment: @kalpit To quote what you said above `root is working it seems but /campaingers/start-process stoped working`. Have you changed the spelling? `campaingers` and `campaigners` are different!

Comment: Thanks its working awesome now.. One quick question how to rewrite www.example.com/love/tribe-world/tribe-test to www.example.com/play/tribe-test.. Have tried this way RewriteRule ^(play/tribe-test.*)$ /love/tribe-world/tribe-test/$1 [L,QSA] but its redirecting me to original url

Comment: still its redirecting me to original url

Comment: Difficult to attend a new questions from comments also I have been cautioned by SO moderators for commenting too much. Suggest opening a new question with clear requirements so that we can attend it independently.